# arithmetic shell_exec() return 0 php

Tags: php, math, return, shell-exec

I have data like this,

```
field1,field2
test,11
test,3
test,14
test,200
test,8
```

and I want to sum all field2. I use shell_exec.

```
$execute = 'x=0;for i in `cut -d\',\' -f2 /app/tibs/tosweb/CCS1/tos/temp/test2.txt`; do let x+=i; echo $x; done';
$output = shell_exec($execute);
echo "<pre>".var_export($output, TRUE)."</pre>\\n";
```

I don't understand, why value of x always return 0?
please help me friend, thank you before.

*sorry my english is bad :P

Answer (score 0):

`cut` doesn't accept a multiple-character delimiter (it considers your escaped delimited as a multi-character because of the escapes). So you can use unescaped:

```
x=0;for i in `cut -d"," -f2 data.txt `; do let x+=i; echo $x; done
```

or `awk` instead

```
x=0;for i in `awk -F\',\' '{ print $1 }'  data.txt `; do let x+=i; echo $x; done
```

To prevent escaping enclose the command with the doule qoutes:

```
$execute = "x=0;for i in `cut -d',' -f2 /app/tibs/tosweb/CCS1/tos/temp/test2.txt`; do let x+=i; echo $x; done";
```

Comment: before I use quote, I was using double quotes. and if I use double quote, return value always string(0).
I try code in other server it's working normally.

I try this in my server:
     shell_exec("echo $((10 + 5))");
and return value is NULL. why if I use aritmetich operation isn't working?

Comment: I tried the code on mine and it's working fine. Are you able to run the command from the SSH cli?